# Dynamic Value Checkbox Vuejs 2

Tags: checkbox, vue.js

I can't get the value of the checkbox.

```html
    <li v-for="mainCat in mainCategories">
      <input type="checkbox" :value="mainCat.merchantId" v-model="mainCategories.merchantId" id="mainCat.merchantId" @click="merchantCategoryId">
    </li>
```

My Methods:

```js
    methods: {    
      merchantCategoryId: function() {
        console.log(this.mainCategories.merchantId)
      }
    }
```

When it clicks I only get true and false for uncheck. TY

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
<div id="demo" >
  <ul>
    <li v-for="mainCat in mainCategories">
      <input type="checkbox" :value="mainCat.merchantId" :id="mainCat.merchantId" v-model="checkedCategories" @click="check($event)"> {{mainCat.merchantId}}
    </li>
  </ul>
  {{ checkedCategories }}
</div>
```

And in your script:

```
var demo = new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data: {
    checkedCategories: [],
    mainCategories: [{
        merchantId: '1'
      }, {
        merchantId: '2'
      }] 
  },
  methods: {
    check: function(e) {
      if (e.target.checked) {
        console.log(e.target.value)
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Check this: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Checkbox

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yMv7y/9206/

Comment: That  is the value of my mainCategories came from the database and I display it by v-for. The purpose of @click is to trigger a method and get the value of the selected checkbox. TY for your reply.

Comment: But that can be achieved without @click.

Comment: I need to achieve it by clicking because I will send that Id back to the database.

Comment: This is what I'm looking for, the example in the docs has no `if (e.target.checked) {
        console.log(e.target.value)
      }`. TY @Deepak you save me tons of time.

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: I can't see why you have *both* :value and  v-model on the input - the :value isn't useful.

Comment: Shouldn't the id be dynamic here? i.e. ":id=" vs just "id="?

Comment: Yes. Good catch. Answer Updated. Thanks @Shaun

Answer (score 1):

```js
new Vue({
el: '#app',
data() {
return {
mainCategory: {
merchantIds: []
},
mainCategories: [{
merchantId: 1,
category: 'first category'
},
{
merchantId: 2,
category: 'second category'
}]

}
},
methods: {    
  merchantCategoryId: function() {
    console.log(this.mainCategory.merchantIds)
  }
}
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<li v-for="mainCat in mainCategories">
  <input type="checkbox" 
  :value="mainCat.merchantId" 
  v-model="mainCategory.merchantIds" 
  id="mainCat.merchantId" 
  @click="merchantCategoryId">
</li>
</div>
```

```
      OR
```

```js
new Vue({
el: '#app',
data() {
return {
mainCategories: [{
merchantId: 1,
category: 'first category'
},
{
merchantId: 2,
category: 'second category'
}]

}
},
methods: {    
  merchantCategoryId: function(event) {
    console.log(event.target.value, event.target.checked)
  }
}
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<li v-for="mainCat in mainCategories">
  <input type="checkbox" 
  :value="mainCat.merchantId"
  id="mainCat.merchantId" 
  @change="merchantCategoryId($event)">
</li>
</div>
```

1.I observed both the mainCategories and v-model value  v-model="mainCategories.merchantId" are the same.
You cannot access the marchantId of mainCategories, this is the mistake what you did apart from that nothing is wrong in the code sample to get the value of marchantId.

2 When your using $event  in the click or change event function no need to use the v-model value.